FFMPEG - Struggling to find correct input audio codec parameters on macOS
I am trying to read my external stereo microphone with ffmpeg within my Qt Windows+macOs application, but I am struggling to obtain consistent correct input codec parameters on macOs. My findings and suspicions so far:
The code I'm using in macOs is the following, where everything returns a successful return code:
 avdevice_register_all();
 
 //macOs only, the same code in windows looks for "dshow" 
 const AVInputFormat *inputFormat = av_find_input_format("avfoundation");
 
 AVFormatContext* inputFormatContext;
 avformat_open_input(&inputFormatContext, inputDevice, inputFormat, NULL);

 avformat_find_stream_info(inputFormatContext, NULL);
 
 //... allocate the codec context for the single input stream and
 // copy the parameters from the stream to the context


In my standalone minimal reproducer this always results on the codec ID of the single stream being AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE, in both macOS and Windows. When I integrate this code in my Qt application on Windows, I get the same result. However, on macOS, most of the times results in the codec id of the stream being AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE (via AV_CODEC_ID_FIRST_AUDIO) and sometimes AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE. Both sample formats are supported by my microphone.
AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE always results in a correct output. AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE results on buzzy noisy audio slowed down to 0.5x, and If in this case I decode with AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE instead of copying the codec parameters from the stream, the output sounds correct again.
I am trying to write generic code, so while enforcing the AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE codec works, I'd rather understand what is happening.
What am I missing? Is Qt interacting in some way that I can't think of? I am compiling and linking my own ffmpeg libraries (6.1.1) and not using Qt's ones.

What was happening was that the Audio Toolbox library was raising an error when calling avformat_open_input: CMIO_Unit_Converter_Audio.cpp:590:RebuildAudioConverter AudioConverterSetProperty(dbca) failed (1886547824)
This caused the codec id of the stream to be set to the dummy AV_CODEC_ID_FIRST_AUDIO instead of the correct one.
